# I am starting in Spring security and I am configuring the FilterChain and it tells me that the antMatcher() function does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-security

Making the filterChain function, the antMatchers function marks me in red as if it does not exist. I am using intelliJ and I have no idea what it could be, I have a theory that I am missing some dependency in the pom.xml but I am not sure anyway I pass my pom.xml

```
package com.main.CitaMedica.config;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig{

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user")
                .password(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("user"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build());
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("admin")
                .password(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("admin"))
                .roles("USER","ADMIN")
                .build());
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE)
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**")
                .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/login/**")
                .anonymous()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        return http.build();
    }


}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>CitaMedica</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CitaMedica</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm just following the steps in this link -> [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Comment: Which is for Spring Security 5.7 (some milestone even) **not** Spring Security 6.x... Which, as your IDE tells you, doesn't have that method anymore.

Comment: @M.Deinum And what do you recommend I do then?

Comment: Read the migration documentation which explains what the replacement is.

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you mean this page? [link](https://www.baeldung.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say your Bean should be like this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain customFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth->auth
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            // the rest of your details
                    )
    // etc
    return http.build;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: And how do you know that it is so? , is that I would like to learn or document spring security in a reliable site

Comment: Now it does not give me errors or anything and if it is the same it should work but I would like to learn on my own in a reliable site. Thanks you so much

Comment: Sure, here’s an official Spring blog post on the matter: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter The difference lies in the inner workings of the filter chain, and before it related to the now deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: ```@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/ignore1", "/ignore2");
    }

} ``` But there are a antMatchers and I can't write it. Why?

Comment: Working with the ´WebSecurityCustomizer´ is another alternative. Nonetheless, this one you write must be an outdated piece of code indeed, because if you write it in your IDE (with Spring Security 6.X.X) you will see it ´Cannot resolve method 'antMatchers' in 'IgnoredRequestConfigurer'´. The current way is to work with ´requestMatchers´.

Comment: so you could say that requestMatchers is the same thing?

Comment: I would say it mostly caters to the same development needs, so to speak

Comment: So this code `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }` is the same as -> read the next comment

Comment: this `@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain customFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth->auth
                        .requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                );
        
        return http.build();
    }` which is from SpringSecurity 6.X